# How do i make sure that a div reserves the remaining horizontal space?

Tags: css, html, css-float, positioning

I am trying to create my own website from scratch, now i ran into a problem considering the HTML/CSS bit.

I am trying to create this standard "header, navigation, content" layout where the header is at the top, the navigation is at the left and the content starts below the header and to the right of the navigation

I use the following piece of code:

```
<div id="head">
 <img src="..." id="logo" style="float:left">
</div>
<div id="nav">
  {some elements}
</div>
<div id="content">
 {some elements}
</div>
```

But as soon as the "style='float:left'" is added to my code, the "content" and "nav" DIV automatically moves to the right of the "head" DIV, is it possible somehow to make the "head" DIV "reserve" the remaining space, so that the "content" and "nav" DIV wont move up to the right of it, but stay below?

Comment: is your nav a fixed width? also if you just want the nav to be below the head add `clear:left` to the styles for it - you need to have a read up on clearing floated elements

Comment: That bootstrap looks quite nice. Will definitely look into it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is called "Collapsed Parent". To prevent this you must clear float.

Add this CSS to your style sheet:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

And add the class "clearfix" to your header, like

```
<div id="head" class="clearfix">
    <img src="..." id="logo" style="float:left">
</div>
```

For more information on clearing floats you can check out this url - http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/css-alignment.php

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="width:250px;">
  <div id="head" style="width:100%; border:1px solid red;">
    <img src="..." id="logo"> Header-Logo
  </div>
  <div id="nav" style="float:left;width:47%;border:1px solid blue;">
    Navigation-Left
  </div>
  <div id="content" style="float:right; width:50%;border:1px solid blue;">
    Content-Right
  </div>
</div>
```

-I think the reason is **"float:left"** inside tag id="head". Because you want to put the header in the top of website so no need to use "float:left" for it.

-You can use **"float:left"** for tag id="nav" and **"float:right"** for tag id="content"

Here is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/4JgA4/119/
=> No need to notice to all my information inside some tags (Just for decorations :D)

Answer (score 1):

Clearing the floats will do.

You need to add a class to your div and in your css as below:

```
.clear
{
    clear:both;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:hidden` to the `#head` element. I don't know why it works, but it ensures that all floated elements are contained inside the parent.